# how to package string labels into savedModel

Tags: tensorflow

I have string labels such as "cat", "dog". Can I feed string labels directly to deep learning models in Tensorflow and get string labels as predictions?  I am looking for the equivalent of sklearn's labelEncoder sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

If this is not possible, is there a way to pack the labels into savedModel protobuf file and retrieve them based on indices during serving time? I am using Estimator's export_savedModel API. Is assets_extra the right way?  The one at https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/55 does not use savedModel format.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle label data in deep learning is to embed the labels in a vector space. Language models do it routinely with [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding). TensorFlow provides [embedding lookup](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/embedding_ops.py) operations that you can use for you purposes.